# EF Core ModelState.IsValid Always return False , Because navigation property is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

There are 2 Models here blow

```
public class Company
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    
    public string Country { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Type { get; set; } = "Client";
    public DateTime CreatedDateTime { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}


public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(25)]
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(25)]
    public string ProductType { get; set; }
    [StringLength(25)]
    public string MarketArea { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string? ReferenceCode { get; set; }
    public string? SpecialStructure { get; set; }
    [StringLength(255)]
    
    public string? Note { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

}
```

As you can see the Company Property is a Navigation Property for EF Core.
but when I submit the form to create the product, the ModelState.IsValid always returns False. and the reason is the navigation property "Company" Is null.
[image]
for now, I can set the navigation property as nullable property to solve this problem.

```
public virtual Company? Company { get; set; }
```

but is there any other solution for this problem?

thanks.

When I Set project property disable
or add #nullable disable at the top of the model file.

the Navigation Property "Company" is not included in the ModelState anymore.
[image]

Comment: Perhaps have `<Nullable>false</Nullable>` in the csproj file...

Comment: I think you can just use [ForeignKey("CompanyId")] annotation above public virtual Company Company {get; set;} Also, if this value has to be set you might seed a "none" value in Company table instead of setting to null, set CompanyID to the none id.  Though I see CompanyID is already required... if you have a pulldown for that and no companies yet seeding the "None" company would take care of it.

Comment: You can add `#nullable disable` at the top of your model file.

Comment: You're binding your datamodel as your viewmodel? Don't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must be using net 6 You will have this problem in all your classes and you have to way to fix it  - make each property nullable, as you did already with Company ,  or remove nullable option from you project config ( or comment it )

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <!--<Nullable>enable</Nullable>-->
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: it works, but why ? may I ask what does this property <Nullable> means?

Comment: @Dan Read this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-reference-types in the end of article

Comment: thanks, Serge, I re-edit the question, I found then I did as you suggested, the Navigation property is removed from ModelState.

Comment: Bumped into this with target framework 7.0 as well.